# Use every single individual value from column in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a column known as "Gender" that has values 1 = Male and 2 = Female.
Each column has a corresponding value next to it, as follows:

```
Gender    Value
1          500
2          300
1          300
2          400
```

and so on.

I want to plot this (with each individual value) on a tableau sheet but if I put either of these measures it just `SUMs` it up by default. Is there a way to plot it like a normal graph with say one attribute as row and the other as column?

Comment: when you say "plot" what kind of visual do you have in mind?
Do you just want a table with all those values or do you want some sort of graphical representation?

Comment: Imagine you had a third column called RowNo. What you actually want to plot is the gender and value number for each RowNo. If you had this then you could drag RowNo to rows and both gender and value to columns or RowNo to rows, value to columns and gender to colour and get a result telling you what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drag Gender to the dimensions section of the data pane (left margin). You might also want to right click on it and edit the aliases.

If you don't want aggregate values in your viz, you can turn that off with the Analysis menu